# Volume of a solution in terms of molality, molar mass and density

Tags: physical-chemistry

I found this equation in "Experiments in Physical Chemistry" by Garland, Nibler, Shoemaker. This is on page 174 (Experiment 9).

$$V=\frac{1000+mM_2}{d}$$

where $V$ is the volume of the solution, $m$ is the molality, $M_2$ is the molar mass of the solute and $d$ is the density of the solution.

The equation was in the middle of a derivation and is shown without any background information. I suppose it should be something pretty straightforward but I am not able to obtain this equation from the definition of molality, density and molar mass.

Comment: Please typeset the equations using mathjax: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange Copy-pasted images are not searchable.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the definitions of molality and molarity, it is mol solute / kg of solvent and mol solute/ Vol of solution in (L). It is not kg of solution in molality. Instead of memorizing a plug and chug formula, would not it be far better to understand the conversion and do it yourself?

I quote an example from General Chemistry by Ebbing and Gammon (2016). Read the strategy:

> Molality to Molarity: An aqueous solution is 0.273 m
> $\ce{KCl}$. What is the molar concentration of potassium chloride,
> $\ce{KCl}$ ? The density of the solution is 1.011 x 10$^3$ g/ L.
>
> Problem Strategy You are asked to determine the molarity of the
> solution, which is the moles of solute $(\ce{KCl})$ per liter of
> solution (volume of $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{KCl}$. The molality tells you that the solution
> contains 0.273 mol $\ce{KCl}$ in $1 \mathrm{~kg}$ of
> water. If we determine the volume of solution that contains $0.273
>  \mathrm{~mol} \ce{KCl}$, we should be able to calculate the
> molarity. Because the solution is made up of only $\ce{KCl}$ and
> water, the solution mass is the mass of 0.273  mol
> $\ce {KCl}$ plus the mass of 1.000 kg of water. Knowing
> the total mass of solution, we then can use the solution density to
> convert from the mass of solution to the volume of solution. The
> molarity is obtained by dividing the moles of solute by the volume of
> solution in liters.

**EDIT:** Now that the OP posted the text, we can discuss the hints.

The equation $$V=\frac{1000+mM_2}{d}$$

is derived from mass balance principle. Keeping the above discussion in mind,

$$Total\hspace{0.15cm}mass\hspace{0.15cm}of\hspace{0.15cm}solution, M=mass _{solvent} + mass_{solute}$$

This is in grams. Now recall the mass volume relation from density. Here $V$ is the volume of solution *not* the solvent.

$$d=\frac{M}{V}$$ or $$M=dV$$

These hints should be enough to derive the desired equation.

Comment: I don't want to memorize the formula. I want to derive it. It is more general that a simple example from Gen. Chem. The equation is just part of a longer derivation.

Comment: I edited my answer in case you want to see where the equation appears.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. Please add the full book reference.

Comment: "Experiments in Physical Chemistry" Garland, Nibler, Shoemaker. This is experimental 9, page 174

Comment: @user130775, Check if you can derive it now.

Comment: I believe I got to the point of Msolution = 1000+Msolute.
What I can't get is how Msolute = molality * (Molar mass) solute

Comment: @user130775, do a dimensional analysis. molality x formula weight gives the mass of solute in grams *added* to 1000 g of solvent.

Comment: Got it. For the mass of the solvent = 1000 g = 1Kg, the molality = mols. Then mols * Molar mass = mass(g). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The equation given is
$$V = \frac{1000 + m \cdot M}{d} \pu{cm3}$$

It only works if you know to enter the quantities' numerical values after expressing them in the conventional units (g for mass, mol/kg for molality, g/mol for molar mass and e.g. g/mL for density). With these specifications, the expression gives the volume of a solution containing 1000 g of solvent.

Another way of writing this, using the modern abbreviation for molality, $b$, and mass, $m$:

$$V_\mathrm{solution} = \frac{m_\mathrm{solvent}  + m_\mathrm{solvent} \cdot b_\mathrm{solute} \cdot M_\mathrm{solute}}{d_\mathrm{solution}}$$

The numerator is the mass of the solution as sum of the mass of solvent and solute. In the cited equation, the 1000 reflects that molarity has units of $\pu{mol kg-1}$ but the molar mass conventionally has units of $\pu{g mol-1}$.

Comment: Good grief! IUPAC has come up with a new symbol for molarity as ($b$)? It is a joke that IUPAC mentions under amount concentration "*Also called ...in **older literature** molarity*". Molarity is as current terminology as possible. It is not going anywhere for several decades. What is the need to come up with new terms when there is no problem with molarity and or its symbols?

Comment: $$m = \frac{n}{m}$$ is confusing as a definition.

Comment: As is $$M = 3 M$$

Comment: One would write [NaOH] = 3 M to imply NaOH concentration is 3 Molar. I wish IUPAC also justified their choices with some context rather than impose it. Do they make their meeting minutes public? On the other hand, $m=\frac{n}{m}$ has symbolic and algebraic problems.

Comment: Sorry typo, I fixed it.

Comment: @Poutnik, Earlier it was molarity.

Comment: @Poutnik, "As you let it there..." There is a time difference in various continents :-). Yes, it is shocking how blatantly IUPAC denigrates molarity, a unit which has worked for centuries and come up with amount concentration.

Comment: @AChem Do you mean molarity as quantity, sharing the unit mol/L with its synonym "amount concentration", or the molarity context specific unit M = mol/L ?

Comment: @Poutnik, Yes, I was wondering about the need to invent amount concentration when molarity does a good job. What is the need to coin a synonym?

Comment: @Achem Molarity is too short, cannot be confused with its vaque generic meaning (amount) in everyday life and perhaps IUPAC guys are paid by the length of the terms. :-P  (deleting older or OT comments)

Comment: @Poutnik as much as I appreciate your sarcasm, there are parts of the world, where the sounds for *r* and *l* are hard to distinguish. Therefore molarity and molality are also hard to keep apart, and the typo potential is high. I personally dislike the term molarity very, very much. And why are you guys hating so much on IUPAC?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン If one of terms molarity vs. molality should go to avoid confusion, I would vote for molality, as it is in my experience used much less (never in my case, but during studying). I do not hate IUPAC, just sometimes wonder over their decisions. In next few decades, I do not give much chances to "amount concentration" against molarity among practical chemists. If it must be, I would prefer molar amount, molar concentration, like we already have e.g. molar conductivity, molar TD state function values, or molar heat capacity.

Comment: @Poutnik One criticism of the term molarity (or molar concentration) is that molar quantities have the chemical amount in the denominator (molar volume, molar mass), but here it merely says to give the amount of substance rather than the mass or the volume of the solute as part of the measure of concentration. It is also a matter of languages. "Stoffmengenkonzentration" is not considered a overly long word in German, and at least it is a single word.

Comment: @Karsten well, molar conductivity is not conductivity per 1 mol either. :-P